# Шифрование пароля JS

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать функцию для шифрования пароля и функцию для дешифрации соответственно, но моих знаний JS очень сильно не хватает, может кто-нибудь мне помочь?

Функция принимает на вход пароль и изменяет его. Сначала до каждого символа добавляются буквы из английского алфавита + цифра 2. То есть будет что-то вроде 123абв => a21b22c23d2аe2бf2вg2 . И затем все это переворачивается.

Еще один пример: 18062000nV- => a21b28c20d26e22f20g20h20i2nj2Vk2-l2 => 2l-2kV2jn2i02h02g02f22e62d02c82b12a

Я пробовал написать что-то, но у меня даже близко не получилось.

Есть ли смысл в такой шифровке и можно ли написать функцию-дешифратор?

Comment: Если алгоритм шифрования известен, то можно написать дешифратор(Если сам алгоритм это подразумевает). Покажите, что вы делали и что не получилось?

Comment: Если речь идёт о паролях, дешифратора типа не должно быть, а во время авторизации происходит сравнение вводимого пароля в зашифрованном виде с образцом в зашифрованном виде, который находится в БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите увидеть реализацию простой функции шифрования и дешифрования, то вот как это может выглядеть.

```
function encryptPassword(password) {
    let encryptedPassword = "";
    let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
        encryptedPassword += alphabet[i % alphabet.length] + "2" + password[i];
    }
    return encryptedPassword.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function decryptPassword(encryptedPassword) {
    let decryptedPassword = "";
    let reversedEncryptedPassword = encryptedPassword.split("").reverse().join("");
    for (let i = 0; i < reversedEncryptedPassword.length; i += 3) {
        decryptedPassword += reversedEncryptedPassword[i + 2];
    }
    return decryptedPassword;
}
```

А если вы хотите в реальном проекте использовать шифрование на js, то лучше всего будет воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками, где есть более серьёзные алгоритмы шифрования, по типу RSA.

Также хочу заметить, что шифрование паролей для хранения, не лучшая идея. Лучше всего воспользоваться односторонними функциями (хэш-функции)

Если надо дополнить ответ, пишите, буду рад помочь

Comment: "Дешифровка" может быть еще проще )) Типа такого `[...encryptedPassword].replace(/(.{2})(.)/g, '$2')].reverse().join('')`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проект у меня не то что бы сильно реальный, я должен буду его запустить буквально на день чтобы защитить. Я знаю о возможности сравнивать пароли для авторизации с помощью готовых библиотек, но мне нужно в моем проекте доставать пароль из БД, расшифровывать и использовать скриптом.

Comment: Если я могу ещё чем-то вам помочь дайте знать, а также если мой ответ вас удовлетворил, прошу отметить его как верный )

Comment: Я чуть попозже попробую ваше решение, и если что спрошу поподробнее

Comment: Действительно, все работает отлично. Честно говоря, не думал что получу ответ на русскоязычном форуме быстрее, чем на основном. Спасибо большое!